# What is the meaning of $[v_1 ; v_2]$?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix

Hi I've always been understanding vector representation such as this $[v_1 ; v_2]$ as a concatenation of the two vectors. So if $ v_1 , v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ then,  $[v_1 ; v_2] \in \mathbb{R}^8$.

I've been reading a paper from ICLR 2020, and I've come across such a notation and I couldn't understand the model unless I understand $[v_1 ; v_2]$ as $v_1 + v_2$, therefore the resulting in a vector size of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Could the meaning of the representation $[v_1 ; v_2]$ vary or is it always a representation of a concatenation?

Thank you everyone in advance.

By the way the paper I was reading is "Sequential Latent Knowledge Selection for Knowledge-Grounded Dialogue". from the equation (7) and (8)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not a $4 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you for your kind interest to my question!! Yeah  the [h_1, h_2, h_3] notation is what makes the vectors h_1, h_2, h_3 concatenate side by side as you suggested, isn't it?. The h are the sentence embeddings via BERT by the way

Comment: If you believe that you know the answer, you can use the Answer box to answer your own question